# Getting Newtonsoft.Json assembly error with latest Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I created a new Web Api project after installing the latest visual studio updates for TC 2.

Added entity `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools: 1.0.0-preview1-final` to the project.

Opened a command line and typed `dotnet ef`.

At this point I got an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Have I got the wrong tools version?

The version I used is what was available from intellisense.

Excerpt from project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final" ,
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: What is the part of depencies of your project.json

Comment: The project dependencies. Should I specify in the framework?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try to add the reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` 8.0.3 *explicitly* in `"dependencies"` or `project.json`. Just add the line `"Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",`. Additionally it could be helpful to search for `Newtonsoft.Json` 7.0.0.0 in the file `project.lock.json` (search for `"Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.0"` or `Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.0`). I'd recommend you to verify which NuGet configuration will be used. Wrong NuGet configuration could prevent loading of the latest version of dependencies.

Comment: I tried to add the Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3 to the project.json, the error persists. I am finding 7.0.0. in the project.lock.json file. Not sure of the best way to remedy that. – Mike Henderson 30 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that saved my day.

1. Delete:

   - `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
   - `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
2. Re-run `dotnet restore`

Comment: Changing your response as the accepted answer because since that's what I ultimately did.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be known issue in [RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5458).

I will mark this as answered and wait for the EF team to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add InternalAbstractions manually in the project.json file:

```
    "Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0",
```

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/366